# Unable to clearInterval()

Tags: javascript, setinterval, addeventlistener, clearinterval

Recently I was working on a stopwatch project in JavaScript. Few things I encountered. First when I assign a variable to the setInterval() function like `let sInterval = setInterval(functionName, milliseconds)`. I was unable to pass it to an eventListener. But when I do this: `sInterval = () => setInterval(functionName, milliseconds)`, I can pass it to the eventListener and start the stopwatch. But when I now want to stop the stopwatch, it doesn't work. I have no idea what's going wrong and don't know how to fix it. Please help :/
Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="keywords" content="stopwatch">
        <meta name="description" content="stopwatch">
        <meta name="author" content="Nick">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stopwatch.css">
        <script src="stopwatch.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>STOPAWATCH</h1>
        <h1>JAVASCRIPT STOPWATCH</h1>
        <div id="stopwatch"></div>
        <button id="button-start">Start</button>
        <button id="button-stop">Stop</button>
        <button id="button-reset">Reset</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: orange;
    font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 100%;
    color: white;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#stopwatch {
    font-size: 3em;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
[id|="button"] {
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    width: 20%;
    height: 80px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 3%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
[id|="button"]:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: orange;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```
window.onload = () => {
    let start = document.getElementById("button-start");
    let stop = document.getElementById("button-stop");
    let reset = document.getElementById("button-reset");
    let stopwatch = document.getElementById("stopwatch");
    let h, m, s;
    initialize = () => {
        h = m = s = "0" + 0;
        stopwatch.innerHTML = `${h}:${m}:${s}`;
    }
    let sInterval = () => setInterval(() => {
        s++;
        if (s < 10 && s[0] !== "0") {
            s = "0" + s;
        } else if (s === 60) {
            m++;
            s = "0" + 0;
        }
        if (m < 10 && m[0] !== "0") {
            m = "0" + m;
        } else if (m === 60) {
            h++;
            m = "0" + 0;
        }
        if (h < 10 && h[1] !== "0") {
            h = "0" + h;
        }
        stopwatch.innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    }, 1000);
    reset.addEventListener("click", () => {
        clearInterval(sInterval);
        initialize();
    }); 
    start.addEventListener("click", sInterval);
    stop.addEventListener("click", clearInterval(sInterval));
    initialize();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `clearInterval()` is not actually "the function you passed to `setInterval()`. It is "the ID returned by the corresponding call to setInterval()"

Try something like this:

```
let sInterval = () => {
    s++;
    ...
};

let intervalID = setInterval(sInterval, 1000);
reset.addEventListener("click", () => {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    ...
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval

Comment: Oh I understand now. Also why I cannot put the setInterval() function directly to the addEventListener but need to assign a function to wrap the setInterval() function up instead

Answer (score 1):

The function `setInterval(cb, interval [, args])` takes 3 arguments and returns an ID for the interval that you have set. This Id is used to clear the interval whenever necessary using the `clearInterval(id)` function. So your code should be something like ->

```
startStopWatch = () => {
    // incremental logic for seconds 
    // goes here
}

const id = setInterval(startStopWatch, 1000);

resetButton.addEventListener('click', () => clearInterval(id))
```